# How to pass a global array to web worker and return it?

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker, postmessage, arraybuffer

last 30-40 minutes I'm trying to understand how exactly works passing an array to a web worker and returning it. For the moment I do the following:

```
var myglobalarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var code = 'self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {' + 
'  var receivedArray = e.data.buffer;' + 
'  var receivedArraysize = receivedArray.length;' + 
'  //doSomethinWithreceivedArray here...' + 
'  self.postMessage(receivedArray, [receivedArray]);' + 
'}, false);';
var blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'text/javascript'});
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var worker = new Worker(blobURL);

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var returnedArray = e.data;
  myglobalarray.length = 0;
  myglobalarray = e.data.slice();
}, false);

var passedArray = new ArrayBuffer(myglobalarray);
worker.postMessage(passedArray, [passedArray]);
```

but still getting the `receivedArray is undefined` and `receivedArray.length is undefined`. Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: Why do you try to use an `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: Read that this is a way to preserve the global array, cause i have another global function that uses it

Comment: The `myglobalarray` is preserved, calling `postMessage` with it will clone the array. You might want to [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage)?

Comment: Ok, but I still receive empty array elements

Answer (score 0):

A simple example, data is JSON serialised

```
var blob = new Blob(["self.addEventListener('message', function(e) { postMessage(e.data); }, false);"]),
    blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    worker = new Worker(blobURL);

worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}, false);

worker.postMessage([1, 2, 3]);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ujKG8/)

Or perhaps this is what you actually want, buffer is transferred? Your title/question is unclear.

```
var blob = new Blob(["self.addEventListener('message', function(e) { postMessage(e.data, [e.data]); }, false);"]),
    blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    worker = new Worker(blobURL),
    myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    bufView = new Int8Array(myArray.length);

bufView.set(myArray);
worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log('transferred buffer in new view:', new Int8Array(e.data));
}, false);

worker.postMessage(bufView.buffer, [bufView.buffer]);
console.log('myArray - preserved:', myArray);
console.log('bufView - cleared by transfer:', bufView);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2R4vX/)

Comment: Just to pass it, not to transfer cause it will be cleared as written in docs. The problem is that the returned by the worker array is empty, which leads in my case to not working collision detection (trying to thread a standard discrete collision of circles). Your last edit doesn't work for me either :( Should I post somewhere the whole code (it works in current non-worker version)?

Comment: Both my examples work for me when using Chromium v27, Chrome v32 and FireFox v26. Are you certain you are using a browser that supports transferrables? In your original code you don't set any values in the buffer, so the length is 0 and contains nothing. `The ArrayBuffer is a data type that is used to represent a generic, fixed-length binary data buffer. You can't directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer; instead, you create an ArrayBufferView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer.`

Comment: Yep, FF v27 and Chrome 32.0.1700.107m, but still get empty returned array, not a single error or warning in Firebug ... Btw for this case I think the easiest and problem-free way is what pointed @Bergi - to use structured clone.

Comment: That would be my first example then.